# How to make adaptive background image increase and returns to its original size constantly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to make page background image in jpg to be animated - I finding a solution for constant smoothly increasing image and then return to it's real size without making smaller. No hover - automatically without any activities from user.

Please help : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this you can do it with css [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sz17jLd/)

```css
.bg {
    width:200px;
    background:url('http://placekitten.com/300/301');
    height:200px;
    background-size:100%;
    -webkit-animation:lar 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes lar {
    0% {
        background-size:100%;
    }
    50% {
        background-size:200%;
    }
    100% {
        background-size:100%;
    }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: @Danko okay thanks for the suggestion should i delete my answer?

Comment: @Akshay thanks! Deleting is not neccesarry - I will be active in answering others : )